# Slider JS file not worked if the file is open locally

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-10

I have write some JavaScript code and use them on IIS then thing work fine but got a problem when I open the file locally.

I have open the source and check the links individually by open the page as view-source:xyz.html

and all links are fine as they should be. I am amazed that why this not worked. Firefox chrome both make error and IE10 is hangs for me ( very amazed on this).

Do someone know why this code not worked.

the code is

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"><script>')
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="ui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js">
</script>
```

is this happen because of difference / and \ in linking to js file.

```
TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function
```

If I check the file in localhost then `jQuery.ui.tabs` is a function but for my local file it's undefined.

I am not sure why that file is not loaded ![enter image description here][1]

Please check the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLIJ0.png

It's work fine in localhost but not in local file. I check the view-source and it's work if you click on them when you do view-source.

Comment: what is exactly you wanted to do here?

Comment: "Firefox chrome both make error" - what is the error?

Comment: Are you using Firebug? Does it give you any output from the Net panel, such as 404s? Can you give us the error?

Comment: my javascript slider work file on IIS.I want to run them by open with Firefox as running locally.

Comment: @LeonardChallis I have check as you say but their is nothing show me when I check locally regarding net panel. When I see script panel then only ui file is missing. not sure what happen.

Comment: @deifwud Sorry I post the error now.

Comment: @BerkerYüceer check my post again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a local file, then the scheme used to open the HTML document will be `file://`

Since you use a scheme relative URI to load jQuery…

```
<script src="//ajax...
```

…you will be trying to use `file://` to access jQuery on Google's servers instead of `http://` or `https://`. This won't work because `file://` is for local files.

You have two options:

- Use an absolute URI for development.
- Make your development environment a better reflection of your production environment by using a local web server.

I recommend the latter option.

Comment: I am confused a little bit more after your answer. I use same technique to link all js file. Only jquery-UI file is not loaded.  Not sure what happened with me. I have used HTml5 boilerplate. is they make some problem with my code.